# Share Counter only works on one post?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, share, posts

I have some code of which only works on one post, however i want it to work on all posts not just the one that has been listed i get the following error:

(Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class shareCount in counter/share-count.php on line 3)

loop.php (this is from my loop code for per post)

```
<?
require("counter/share-count.php");
$obj=new shareCount("http://google.com");
echo "Tweets: ".$obj->get_tweets();
echo "<br>Facebook: ".$obj->get_fb(); 
echo "<br>Google+: ".$obj->get_plusones();
?>
```

share-count.php (this is the file thats executable on request)

```
<?
class shareCount {
private $url,$timeout;
function __construct($url,$timeout=10) {
$this->url=rawurlencode($url);
$this->timeout=$timeout;
}

function get_tweets() { 
$json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $this->url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
}

function get_fb() {
$json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls='.$this->url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
return isset($json[0]['total_count'])?intval($json[0]['total_count']):0;
}

function get_plusones()  {
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"'.rawurldecode($this->url).'","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
$curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
return isset($json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'])?intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] ):0;
}

private function file_get_contents_curl($url){
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
$cont = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
{
die(curl_error($ch));
}
return $cont;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please format your code!

Answer (score 0):

Your included file `counter/share-count.php` defines the `shareCount` class every time it is included, which is why you are seeing the error. You can fix this by either using [`require_once()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) or check to see if the class is already defined using [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) and only defining it if the result is `false`.

Using `require_once()` to replace `require()`:

```
require_once("counter/share-count.php");
// ... rest of your code
```

Using `class_exists()`:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'shareCount' ) ):
class shareCount{
    // your class implementation
}
endif; // class_exists
```

Comment: Please see me other answer, I'm trying to get the URL to work for each post now

Comment: Got this all working but because i have to call it from another document in the website, its crashing the website, is there a way to call it in the webpage itself, without calling it from a different document?